# JSON HTTP response body from rails seems to be invalid

Tags: json, http-headers, ruby-on-rails-5

I am working with rails, and returning a json response with the below method

```
def return_json
    render json: params
end
```

When i am viewing the response on chrome developers tools, everything seems to be right. But when i trace the HTTP response on wireshark, on HTTP response body it seems that some extra characters exists.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.10.3
Date: Wed, 05 Jul 2017 17:07:48 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Runtime: 0.433854
X-Request-Id: f46a0e87-6969-4285-9b80-da0223edac01
X-Powered-By: Phusion Passenger 5.1.5
Status: 200 OK

49
{"device_attributes":[{"id":"85","value":"35"},{"id":"80","value":"65"}]}
0
(extra empty line)
```

I'm talking about the number `49` which is in hex and it seems to be the length of the JSON string. And after that it follows a `0` with an empty line.

[Wireshark screenshot which shows the response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGSrO.png)

First of all, i would like to ask, what a valid HTTP response look like?
I think that after headers, follows an empty line and then the response body and after that nothing.

And second why rails do that and if there is a way to change that. I think that rails do that, because i get the same response from `apache + phusion passenger` and also `puma`. Also i tried this from some other code, not related to rails, and the HTTP response it was as i explained earlier and not as rails does.

Answer (score 0):

I did not found out the answer i was looking for, but a workaround in order for the extra info to be removed, is to render as follows:

```
render plain: ActiveSupport::JSON.encode({ result: :ok })
```

This work around does set content-type as 'text/plain' and not 'application/json'. If you set content-type in render options as 'application/json' this extra info are being displayed again.

So i will assume that has something to do with the json renderer module, but i can't research it more at this time.